# Как вывести звук в Ассемблере в DOS?

Tags: ассемблер

В интернете я нашел такое решение, но если способы сделать это короче? По заданию мне нужно просто подать любой звук в прирывании contorl+c.

```
ASTACK SEGMENT STACK
    DB 2048 DUP(?)
ASTACK ENDS
DATA      SEGMENT
        KEEP_CS DW 0 
        KEEP_IP DW 0 

DATA      ENDS


CODE      SEGMENT
          ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA, SS:ASTACK

rout proc far 
    push ax 
    push dx 
 ;--------------------------------------------- Часть кода выводящая звук
    mov di,6000 ;частота звука
    mov bx,20   ;длительность
    mov al,0b6H
    out 43H,al
    mov dx,0014H
    mov ax,4f38H
    div di
    out 42H,al
    mov al,ah
    out 42H,al
    in al,61H
    mov ah,al
    or al,3
    out 61H,al
    l1:     mov cx,2801H
    l2:     loop l2
    dec bx
    jnz l1
    mov al,ah
    out 61H,al
 ;---------------------------------------------
    pop dx 
    pop ax 

    mov al,20h
    out 20h,al

iret
rout endp 



main proc far
    push ds
    sub ax,ax
    push ax
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah, 35h
    mov al, 23h
    int 21h
    mov KEEP_IP, bx
    mov KEEP_CS, es

    push ds
    mov dx,offset rout

    mov ax,seg rout 
    mov ds,ax 
    mov ah,25h 
    mov al,23h 
    int 21h 

    pop ds 

begin:
    mov ah,0
    int 16h
    cmp al,3
    jnz begin

    int 23h 



    CLI
    PUSH DS
    MOV  DX, KEEP_IP    
    MOV  AX, KEEP_CS
    MOV  DS, AX
    MOV  AH, 25H
    MOV  AL, 23H
    INT  21H          
    POP  DS
    STI

ret

Main endp
code ends
    end Main
```

Comment: Ассемблер — это, вообще-то, не про "короче". Но попробуйте выдать символ с кодом 07h, например, через функцию 02h, 09h или 40h прерывания 21h. Не уверен, но вдруг...